# Irreducibility is preserved under ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am studying Field Theory from class notes of a senior and need help in deducing an argument.

> The argument is as follows: 
>   Let $\sigma: K\to L$ be an isomorphism of Fields and let $g$  be an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$.  Then prove that $\sigma g$ is irreducible in $L[x]$.

I tried by arguing that let $\sigma g$ be reducible but I am not able to get a contradiction which I think should be f is reducible.

Comment: If $\sigma f=g_1g_2$, $f=(\sigma^{-1}g_1)(\sigma^{-1}g_2)$.

Comment: No, $f$ could be reducible. This would be no contradiction. It is about $g$ and $\sigma(g)$.

Comment: Why considering $g$ as an irreducible factor of a bigger polynomial $f$, and not just wondering if an irreducible polynomial is still irreducible?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde can you please elaborate on what should be my approach to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma g = hi$ then $g = (\sigma^{-1}h)
(\sigma^{-1}i)$ because the isomorphism $\sigma$ induces isomorphism between their polynomial ring, which is $\sum a_iX^i \mapsto \sum (\sigma a_i)X^i$, and this preserves the degree. contradiction.

Comment: You should also say that the degree is preserved under isomorphism, factorising a polynomial in not enough to say it's reducible.

Comment: You’re right. Thank you. I’ll fix it.

Comment: @Konbuuu how you are sure that both $\sigma^{-1}h  $ $\sigma^{-1}i $ have degree greater than i?

Comment: @Konbuuu why  degree is preseved in isomorphism ? Can you please explain!!

Comment: @XWLPDK Please see the explicit definition of the isomorphism which I wrote in the answer. The isomorphism maps 0 to 0, and nonzero elements to nonzero elements. So the highest term goes to the highest term, because its coefficient is nonzero

Comment: @XWLPDK just give a look at how the induced isomorphism is defined and notice that $\sigma(x)=0 \iff x=0$ as $\sigma$ is an isomorphism. As the degree is defined as the "highest" non null coefficient, the degree cannot change under isomorphism.

Comment: @Giacomo Parolin my comments were made when the answer was not edited. The edit in answer is sufficient to explain !!